# Rewrite all URLs to a new domain and include an extra parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Which .htaccess redirect rule(s) would one use to create all of the following forwards?

- http://old.io --> http://new.com?pa=va
- http://old.io/ --> http://new.com/?pa=va
- http://old.io/abc --> http://new.com/abc?pa=va
- http://old.io#def --> http://new.com#def?pa=va
- http://old.io/abc#def --> http://new.com/abc#def?pa=va

. . . and include any other arbitrary parameters:

- http://old.io?p2=v2 --> http://new.com?pa=va&p2=v2
- http://old.io/?p2=v2 --> http://new.com/?pa=va&p2=v2
- http://old.io/abc?p2=v2 --> http://new.com/abc?pa=va&p2=v2
- http://old.io#def?p2=v2 --> http://new.com#def?pa=va&p2=v2
- http://old.io/abc#def?p2=v2 --> http://new.com/abc#def?pa=va&p2=v2

Comment: The following solves the first set of redirects, _except_ those with # signs . . .
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.io$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1?pa=va [R=301,L]`

Comment: So you want `http://old.io/ ` to be redirected to both `http://new.com/?p1=v1` and `http://new.com/?p1=v1&p2=v2`! It's unclear what you're asking. Please consider editing your question and describing the problem more clearly.

Comment: Good catch, @sepehr. I just corrected the bottom set of examples.

Consider each bullet a separate HTTP request. So for example, ``http://old.io/abc#def`` would forward to``http://new.com/abc#def?p1=v1`` while ``http://old.io#def?p2=v2`` forwards to ``http://new.com#def?pa=va&p2=v2``.

Comment: Well, ok. One more note; Even though `http://new.com#def?pa=va&p2=v2` is a valid URL, the querystring gets discarded by the server as it's coming after the `#`. It needs to come before the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you need to add a `pa=va` to the query string of any possible constructed URL:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if the host matches old.io,
# You might want to add www\. to that.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.io

# Rewrite URLs with empty querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1?pa=va [L,R]

# Rewrite URLs with non-empty querystring    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1?pa=va&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
```

Note that the anchor hash part needs to come **after** the query string.

You can [test it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), if you wish.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you, @sepher.

Only ``http://old.io/abc#def?p2=v2`` doesn't work. It comes out with two query strings. i.e. ``http://new.com/abc?pa=va#def?p2=v2``.

Comment: Also, I took your advice and added a _www_ check as ``RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.io``

Comment: While that URL is valid, it's not properly constructed. As I said,  the query strings should come before the anchor hash, not after them. The correct URL would be: `http://old.io/abc?p2=v2#def` which is working fine with the above rewrites. Other note is that you don't need the parenthesis with `www` as you're not capturing anything there.

Comment: Got it. You are right. Thank you.

Any interest in answering [an easier question about adding a space to a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397961/rewrite-a-url-to-include-an-extra-parameter-with-a-space-in-it)?