# Rewrite a URL to include an extra parameter with a space in it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Now that [.htaccess rewrites all URLs and includes a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351136/rewrite-all-urls-to-a-new-domain-and-include-an-extra-parameter), how can that parameter have a space in it?

For example

- http://old.io --> http://new.com?pa=v%20a

While `%20` works when [testing in a .htaccess simulator](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), it doesn't work on my DreamHost account.

- http://new.com?pa=v%20a --> http://new.com?pa=v0a
- http://new.com?pa=v\ a --> [http://new.com?pa=v a](http://new.com?pa=v%20a)
- http://new.com?pa=v%2520a --> http://new.com?pa=v520a
- adding the *[NE](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne)* flag doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you provide your current `.htaccess`?

Comment: `%20` should work just fine. What do you exactly mean by **it doesn't work**? Please read about how to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it is easier for others to understand the problem.

Comment: I am using the htccess file linked to at the top of my post. The problems I am having showing in the bottom set of bullets.

Comment: What's the result when you use `%20` in your rewrite rules? Please mention me so I can be notified when you comment here.

Comment: Hi, @sepehr. ``http://new.com?pa=v%20a`` become ``http://new.com?pa=v0a``.

Answer (score 0):

You're right; Even though adding `%20` works in the simulator, it does not work on a real httpd server.

To add a space, you need to escape it with a `\`. Here's what your htaccess file looks like:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if the host matches old.io,
# You might want to add www\. to that.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.io

# Rewrite URLs with empty querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1?pa=v\ a [L,R]

# Rewrite URLs with non-empty querystring    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1?pa=v\ a&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
```

Notice `pa=v\ a` in `RewriteRule` directives.